# PHP SQL injection not working

Tags: php, sql-injection

Hello I just wanna ask about SQL injection currently I am working on a login page but I am getting a little problem about SQL injection I am currently testing a batched SQL code as shown below, I have not yet put an SQL parameter, but it doesn't seem to be working on an SQL injection. My validation is based on row count if it is equal to 0 it will destroy the session and redirected to the index again. The code seems to be working fine, but I am afraid why is it working properly without putting any SQL parameter to prevent SQL injection. I hope someone could explain it, thanks in advance

**secured_page.php**

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

// Set session variables
$_SESSION["email"] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION["password"] = md5($_POST['password']);

if (isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    header('Location: profile.php');    
}
else {
    header('Location: index.php');  
}

?>
```

**profile.php**

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
include('header.php'); 

include('db_connect.php');
$email = $_SESSION["email"];
$password = $_SESSION["password"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user where email = '$email' and password = '$password' LIMIT 1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo $result->num_rows;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. " " . $row["email"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    header('Location: unset_session.php');  
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    header('Location: index.php');  
}

?>
<br>
<a href="unset_session.php">Logout</a>

<?php 
$conn->close();
include('footer.php'); 
?>
```

Comment: Are you using mysqli or pdo ?

Comment: So your question is "Why can't I sql-inject something in this seemingly sql-vulnerable code?", correct?  Then you should show us what you tried to inject. The answer can likely be figured out by dumping your `$sql` and of course knowing what's in the database.

Comment: *"but it doesn't seem to be working on an SQL injection"* - you need to be clearer on that and the rest of your question. It's hard to say what failed you, because there is no code to support your question. @jester

Comment: I have moved on. @ me if you need more help, I won't be keeping this tab open. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Do like this to prevent SQL Injection

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user where email = ? and password = ? LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

$result->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);

/* execute query */
$result->execute();
//Now you can use $result variable like you used before
echo $result->num_rows;
```

Learn more on preparing statements here : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: My problem is whenever I use sql inject I am getting a 0 row. And the algorithm seems to be working fine to prevent sql injection. But anyway thanks for answering and giving some code param :)